# Function not found in current context

Tags: c#, methods

I'm trying to call a function but keep getting an error saying it doesn't exist in this current context. It's for a class assignment. I'm not sure why it's not recognizing the function.

```
using System;               
public class Program
{

    public int W(int a, int b)
    {   
        return 0;   
    }

    public static void Main()   
    {
        int j= W(1,1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error means that the function is not in the current scope. In your case the function can only belong to an instance of class Program (so you cannot call it from the static method).

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is:

[Compiler Error CS0120](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120)

> An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or
> property 'member'
>
> In order to use a non-static field, method, or property, you must
> first create an object instance.

**Solution**

Change:

```
public int W(int a, int b)
```

to:

```
public static int W(int a, int b)
```

Basically, you can't call *instance members* from a *static method* without an instance.

---

Further reading:

[static (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)

[Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

[Instance Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/instance-constructors)

Answer (score 0):

in static method you must use static member otherwise not found in current context

so you must type static before your type(int) and then call it